# how to change photo placeholder it work with label but other tag stop working?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am in need for some help i make a select image file and output when select i am able too see my picture using label but however when i change to button it stop working

This is my code with the label

```
<div style="left: 1100px; top: 200px; position: fixed;">
                                        <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
                                        <p><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg" id="output" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;"/></p>
                                        <br/>
                                        <p style="margin-left: 45px;"><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 5px; position: static;">Select Image</label></p>
                                        </div>

                                     


                                        <script>
                                        var loadFile = function(event) {
                                            var image = document.getElementById('output');
                                            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                                        };
                                        </script>
```

When i change to button tag the picture dont display or change  anymore in my page

how can i solve this?

Comment: Hi, i just tested your code and it seems fine, https://codepen.io/jankees/pen/bGogMEN

Comment: that weird is not showing up for me in my html page

Comment: oh i realize why now i put them in my form inside that why is not working ...

Comment: glad it's solved!